# Swift 3 / Xcode text alignment to imageview

Tags: swift, xcode, text, imageview, alignment

I need your help for a (maybe?) stupid question.

I'm new to Swift and I still have to understand a couple of things in Xcode.
One of these is TEXT ALIGNMENT.

I want to align a label to an imageview just like the picture I have attached.
Can someone please help me undertsand how can I do it?
Is it just a matter of constraints or is there something else I have to do via code?

Thank you in advance.

[I'd like to achieve this in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIQtM.png)

Comment: Can you please explain the screenshot? Which image and which label?

Comment: I know that Swift is not related to the result I want to achieve but I've asked if there were any code (in swift) I had to write to get what I wanted.

Comment: @PGDev I'd like to have an image view (the square in my screenshot) and a label aligned in a way that:  1) if the label is a single line, is aligned centrally to the image view   2) if the label is multiple lines, it mus be top aligned to the image view.        I don't know the number of line of the label. It must adapt dinamically

Comment: Below the text SINGLE LINE?

Answer (score 0):

In the Attributes Inspector of Interface Builder, on the Label, set the Lines property to 0. This will act like text wrap. You don't have to do anything to align it except manually drag the label next to the image view.

Answer (score 0):

you can do with constraint

for image set leading and top constraint   and make Top Base alignment to Label and Image  by select to Item check this image

[image]

Comment: Works when you have multiple lines but the label won't be centered to the imageview if it is single line :(